# Application Insights: Profiler Trace Duration messed up

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am looking at application insights and investigating in a performance issue:

-> Application Insights -> Performance -> Select an operation -> Profiler traces

[image]

The duration for that operation at the left of the screen is (**7462.45 ms**) while the total duration of the events for this operation is (**15509.03 ms**). How could that happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time on the left represents the length of time that the request took according to a "clock on the wall". The length of time on the right is the total CPU time or thread time that the request used. If the request is multi-threaded and work is being done in parallel, more total time will be used than what is represented in wall clock time.

We are working on a UI that will explain this situation better.

Comment: Thanks @Chuck Weininger! Can you please mention what are the events that can contribute to this time on right side? For instance, there is AWAIT_TIME (7406.76 ms) which might be excluded from the "Clock on the wall", but this doesn't seem its a thread time neither CPU time, because the  request is sitting idle at that point. Seems confusing a bit, and just need to understand whats happening there.

Comment: Everything contributes to the time on the right side, but sometimes the time is counted twice. If a request spawns multiple threads, both of those threads may be executing at the same time, thus using more CPU time that the wall clock time of the request. If you send an email to service profiler help @microsoft dot com with a screenshot of your trace, my team can help you understand what is happening.